# Function does not start when converting date, swift

Tags: swift, date, func

declare a delegate:

```
weak var delegate: ChangeDatePickerValueDelegate?
```

Create protocol

```
protocol ChangeDatePickerValueDelegate: AnyObject {
    func convertDate(dateOnPicker: Date) -> String
    func datePickerChanged(text: String, cell: UICollectionViewCell)
}
```

The function is fired when there is a change in the value of the datePicker

```
@objc
func handleDatePicker(sender: UIDatePicker) {
    dateTextField.text = delegate?.convertDate(dateOnPicker: datePicker.date)
    print(dateTextField.text)
}
```

after execution, the execution of this part does not start

```
extension AddContactsController: ChangeDatePickerValueDelegate {
func convertDate(dateOnPicker: Date) -> String {
    return (presenter?.dateFormatter(datePicker: dateOnPicker))!
}
```

Why is execution not happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Don't put in images of code - add the actual code to the question.  make it easy for people to help you.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't assign the delegate to `AddContactsController` anywhere, so you need to have a reference of the object (the class you defined `weak var delegate` in there) and do it like this:

datePicker.delegate = self

somewhere in the code like in `viewDidLoad()` of `AddContactsController`
assuming your object name is datePicker.